# chrome extension to automaticly open highlighted commands from webbrowser in terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, chrome-extension

As the title suggests, is there a chrome extension to automatically open highlighted commands of web browser in the terminal?

Wouldn't this be great?

Comment: Just to be sure: on a web page, there is a command in the text, you'd like to select it and run it? I don't want to overload you with answers, but it *can* be done if that is what you mean :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the way Chrome is designed to be self contained, there likely isn't any way to make an extension to do this. However, most newer Linux users don't seem to know that if you highlight text with your mouse, you can middle-click and paste it anywhere else. So you can just highlight the text in the browser and middle-click it into your terminal.

Comment: handy for mouse users I suppose, however I do not use a mouse. Was also looking for some faster way than highlighting the text, alt tabbing to terminal, pasting to terminal.

Comment: Try using "Sloppy" focus on your mouse settings. You don't have to alt-tab, just hover the mouse over. Also, if you had an extension to do that, it would be really insecure because it would require root access and browsing the web with root access is just not a very good idea.

Comment: you are right about root access for sure. thanks for your input.